# checkboxes as radio buttons with prop()

Tags: jquery

I have 3 lists (ul) and inside them there are checkboxes. If I check one and going to check another, the one checked before must be unchecked (a checkbox from one list shouldn't affect another from another list):

```
<!--printed from php -->
<div id="checkboxes">
    <ul>
        <li><input type="checkbox" /></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" /></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" /></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li><input type="checkbox" /></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" /></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" /></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li><input type="checkbox" /></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" /></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This is the JQuery code:

```
$(document).on('change', '#checkboxes li input[type=checkbox]', function() {
    $(this).closest('ul').not(this).prop('checked', false);

    //alert(this);
});
```

The alert is working but not the `prop()`. Where is the problem?

Comment: Users expect certain behaviors, and changing them is poor practice.

Comment: Because I'm reusing code and it's easier for me 2 lines of js than changing all those types. Anyways there's no difference so the behaviour is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where is the problem?

Not selecting `input` element following `.closest("ul")` to set `checked` property of `input` elements instead of `ul` parent element ?

Try adding `.find("input")` after call to `.closest()`

```js
$(document).on('change', '#checkboxes li input[type=checkbox]', function() {
  $(this).closest('ul').find("input").not(this).prop('checked', false);
  //alert(this);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="checkboxes">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're finding the closest element by selector of `ul` and immediately use `.not()` which doesn't expect to be work. Cause, the clicked element right now is `checkbox` itself, not the `ul` element. Use `.find()` and after that chaining with `.not()`. Anyway try this code :

```
// can simplified selector like
// $(document).on('change', '#checkboxes :checkbox',
$(document).on('change', '#checkboxes li :checkbox', function() {
   $(this).closest('ul').find(':checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', false); 
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/rcw7q1pz/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'll accept the other since it was the first one, anyways +1!

Comment: Yeah, never mind, as long as the problem got solved. You're welcome mate.